# LazyInitializationException is getting when trying to assign a HashSet

Tags: java, hibernate

```
 private Set<Employee> assignees = new HashSet<>();  



 public Set<Employee> getAssignees() {
            return assignees;
        }

        public void setAssignees(Set<Employee> assignees) {
            this.assignees = assignees;
        }
```

I used the above method in below code and when running that code i am getting this exception.

```
 `Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:`
```

It is coming from the execution of
 `agendaInfo.setAssignees(item.getAssignees());` line.
Why is it getting this exeption?

```
@Override
        public List<AgendaContentDTO> getAgendasByMeetingId(Long meetingId) {

            List<Agenda_content> agendas = extendedAgendaContentRepository.getAgendasByMeetingId(meetingId);
            List<AgendaContentDTO> agendaDTOS = new ArrayList<>();

            Long currentUser = utils.getCurrentEmployeeId();

            for (Agenda_content item: agendas){

                AgendaContentDTO agendaInfo = new AgendaContentDTO();

                agendaInfo.setId(item.getId());
                agendaInfo.setTitle(item.getTitle());
                agendaInfo.setContent(item.getContent());
                agendaInfo.setMeetingId(item.getMeeting().getId());
                agendaInfo.setMeetingMeetingName(item.getMeeting().getMeetingName());
                agendaInfo.setAssignees(item.getAssignees());

              agendaDTOS.add(agendaInfo);
            }
            return agendaDTOS;
        }

public interface ExtendedAgendaContentRepository extends Agenda_contentRepository {

    @Query("select distinct e.meeting from Agenda_content e join e.assignees a where a.id =:assigneeId")
    public List<Meeting> getMeetingsAssignedToMe(@Param("assigneeId") long assigneeId);

    @Query("select distinct e from Agenda_content e where e.meeting.id =:meetingId")
    public List<Agenda_content> getAgendasByMeetingId(@Param("meetingId") long meetingId);


}
```

Comment: is it a hibernate project? then add the correct tag.

Comment: Show the source code for `extendedAgendaContentRepository`. Are you using Spring?

Comment: yes.I am using spring.

Comment: ` @Query("select distinct e from Agenda_content e where e.meeting.id =:meetingId")
    public List<Agenda_content> getAgendasByMeetingId(@Param("meetingId") long meetingId);`

Comment: share your POJO

Answer (score 0):

Collection are lazy loading in hibernate, So when you loaded your data from getAgendasByMeetingId, hibernate load the list of  Agenda_content but not there collection(Assignees).

LazyInitializationException is geeting due to no Transaction(No Session open) avilable in your 
 `public List<AgendaContentDTO> getAgendasByMeetingId(Long meetingId) {` code

If you are using spring then mark your method with @Transaction
or in hibernate you need to open a session

Or you can use fetchType=FetchType.EAGER on your collection, so hibernate load all getAssignees during load Agenda_content.